# How to write a generic method for get request which is fetching data from Databased?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am new to coding and trying to create method in more generic way. can someone help me here to understand the generics.

I have two method in my DAO class getEmployeeMasterList() and getEmployeeListById(Integer empId) to fetch record from database:

```
    public List<EmployeeMaster> getEmployeeMasterList() {

    return appHibernateUtils.getSession(sessionFactory).createCriteria(EmployeeMaster.class).list();
}

    public EmployeeMaster getEmployeeListById(Integer empId) {

    if(empId == 0 || empId == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return (EmployeeMaster) appHibernateUtils.getSession(sessionFactory)
    .createCriteria(EmployeeMaster.class)
    .add(Restrictions.eq(AppConstant.EMP_ID, empId))
    .uniqueResult();
}
```

Can someone help me how to construct a generic method from above two if it is possible.

And in service class I have two method which set database data with Pojo and send to UI

```
    public List<EmployeeMasterDto> getEmployeeMasterList() {

    List<EmployeeMaster> empDataList= empMasterDao.getEmployeeMasterList();

    List<EmployeeMasterDto> listToSend = new ArrayList<>();
    for(EmployeeMaster data : empDataList) {
        EmployeeMasterDto dtoObject = new EmployeeMasterDto();
        dtoObject.setEmpId(data.getempId());
        dtoObject.setEmpName(data.getEmpName());

        listToSend.add(dtoObject);
    }
    return listToSend;
}


    public EmployeeMasterDto getEmployeeListById(Integer empId) {

    if(empId == null)
        return null;

    EmployeeMaster empData = empMasterDao.getEmployeeListById(empId);       
    EmployeeMasterDto dataToSend = new EmployeeMasterDto();
    dataToSend.setEmpId(empData.getEmpId());
    dataToSend.setEmpName(empData.getEmpName());
    return dataToSend;
}
```

Please help me here to construct a generic method from the above two methods.

Comment: You can achieve this Using [Specification](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/Specification.html) from spring data jpa. How to use it? - Check [here](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) and [here](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-specifications)

Comment: Thanks Hemant but I am finding it bit difficult to construct one generic method, can you help me to do it for this one so that I will have a reference and a clear understanding